# DNS Problem. www.mysite not working, but mysite.com does?

Tags: domain-name-system

Having a slight issue. www.mysite.com returns a "server not found" error but site.com works fine.

I have contacted my dedicated server provider (volumedrive) and they are saying there is nothing wrong with the DNS settings. I have taken a look at the DNS settings but to be honest I am a little lost.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: Forgot to list the domain. The domain is eye-tester.info (and www.eye-tester.info)

Comment: This would be much easier to debug if you actually gave us the real domain names.

Comment: Sorry, the domain is eye-tester.info (and www.eye-tester.info)

Comment: Getting a bit strange result while diagnosing eye-tester.info. Have you been changing the NS settings very recently?

Answer (score 2):

Your domain eye-tester.info is delegated in the .info zone to the DNS servers ns1.eye-tester.info and ns2.eye-tester.info. The .info DNS server returns A records for both these servers pointing at 173.242.113.190.

The DNS server at 173.242.113.190, however, says that eye-tester.info has the NS records ns1.volumedrive.com and ns2.volumedrive.com (which don't exist) and doesn't define A records for either ns1.eye-tester.info or ns2.eye-tester.info. These problems will cause erratic resolution of eye-tester.info records and may explain why www is not working.

If you want the server at 173.242.113.190 to handle DNS for eye-tester.info, then you'll need to change the NS records it returns to ns1.eye-tester.info and ns2.eye-tester.info and define A records for ns1.eye-tester.info and ns2.eye-tester.info. You should also consider having your secondary DNS on a separate server so that your domain doesn't become completely unresolvable when your primary server is being rebooted, etc.

If you want volumedrive to handle the DNS, then you'll need to set up your DNS zone with them and change your domain settings to use their DNS servers.

---

NS records at the .info servers:

```
$ dig ns eye-tester.info @a0.info.afilias-nst.info

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R1 <<>> ns eye-tester.info @a0.info.afilias-nst.info
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17525
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;eye-tester.info.               IN      NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
eye-tester.info.        86400   IN      NS      ns2.eye-tester.info.
eye-tester.info.        86400   IN      NS      ns1.eye-tester.info.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.eye-tester.info.    86400   IN      A       173.242.113.190
ns2.eye-tester.info.    86400   IN      A       173.242.113.190
```

NS records at 173.242.113.190:

```
$ dig ns eye-tester.info @173.242.113.190

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R1 <<>> ns eye-tester.info @173.242.113.190
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18970
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;eye-tester.info.               IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
eye-tester.info.        86400   IN      NS      ns2.volumedrive.com.
eye-tester.info.        86400   IN      NS      ns1.volumedrive.com.
```

No A record for ns1.eye-tester.info at 173.242.113.190:

```
$ dig a ns1.eye-tester.info @173.242.113.190

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R1 <<>> a ns1.eye-tester.info @173.242.113.190
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 9091
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns1.eye-tester.info.           IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
eye-tester.info.        86400   IN      SOA     ns1.volumedrive.com. email.omitted.example.org. 2010071706 86400 7200 3600000 86400
```